# Can't seem to get $_GET['id'] to work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to get data from a database but cant seam to get the following working, does anyone know why?

I have tried `print_r` too and shows nothing, the db connection and everything is working too.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT id, title, content FROM articles WHERE id = $id');
$query->execute();
$article = $query->fetchall();
```

This does however `print_r` the id from the URL correctly.

```
print_r($_GET);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: so much for prepared statements :)

Comment: @Ghost You are one of Stack's prepared statements "Ambassadors" ;)

Comment: Just a random question, but why do i, on everything iv asked a question about, get down-voted? Its just a question.

Comment: @haydenbarton96 *"but why do i, on everything iv asked a question about, get down-voted?"* - wasn't me.

Comment: I wasn't blaming it on you Fred, sorry! Just wondered why as iv asked 3 questions and got down-voted on them all for some reason, i was starting to think there was a hidden rule or something what im not doing haha

Comment: @haydenbarton96 OT: well, since downvotes on questions are free, its so easy to unleash even when its unreasonable. anyways you can't please everybody

Comment: @Fred-ii- haha lol. you're part of that club too :). anyways why not use it. it take's no effort to use it anyway.

Comment: Ah yes i guess your right, cant please everyone.

Comment: @Ghost I'll usually just "pawn it off" rather than doing a rewrite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Important note:

Variables inside single qoutes are not interpolated. They're just literal strings

Much better to bind them properly:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT id, title, content FROM articles WHERE id = :id');
$query->bindParam(':id', $id);
$query->execute();
$article = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Probably helps, too, if one watches case -- i.e. `fetchall != fetchAll` ;)

Comment: @JeremyMiller actually that will still work, i don't know why PHP does this though. and of course it still much better to follow the correct casing

Comment: Oh, yes, my bad.  I get -- as I think we all do -- into so many languages that I cross a few rules.  When we assume something like case-insensitivity will remain, though, I always ask, "For how long?", so I default to the case in the docs.  Thanks!

Comment: I just changed the single quotes to double quotes, thats letting me print the array successfully now with print_r. Will upvote and mark as answer when i can :)

Comment: @haydenbarton96 yeah the quotes is also an issue. but utilize prepared statements instead, don't directly inject your variables in the query string, that makes your query unsafe and prone to sql injection. thats the sense of using `->prepare()`

Comment: The whole project im working on is local so there will be no sql injection, but if i plan to take it public then i will go over it all, change a few things and make it secure, thanks for the tip though!

Comment: @haydenbarton96 i don't think thats enough reason not to prepare queries. if it goes public, then thats just another coding work. but anyways glad this helped

Comment: Ill give it a go and carry on tomorrow, im newish to php so ill gain more knowledge, ill do it tomorrow of-course as its 4:35am right now..